# Converting the dataframe to JSON takes lot of time

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a dataframe of 10,000 records which I want to convert to JSON format and send back to webservice. But df.toJSON().collect() takes a lot of time [~10 secs]. Can anyone suggest if there is a way to reduce this time

df.toJSON().collect()

Comment: Can you give a sample of JSON and your code?

Comment: @Kafels It can be like this : [{‘item_code: 1234’, ‘qty: 2’}, {‘item_code: 2345, ‘qty: 3’}, .....]

Comment: How are you forwarding the json to the service? Can you do this in distributed fashion instead of collecting to driver?

Comment: In a distributed fashion means using any Spark apis?

Answer (score 0):

it could be a few different things ...

1. json can take a while to serialize especially if you are using the R or Python api because it is a separate process and needs to go back and forth between the native JVM executors on the worker nodes to serialize/deserialize objects
2. if you performed any "wide transformations" like aggregation or join prior to df.collect() you most likely triggered a shuffle which will result in 200 default partitions being written to disk hence when you call collect it has to retrieve that data from disk which is slower than retrieving from RAM
3. although your data set is small you may need to increase the default executor RAM, executor cores (slots), # of executors, and re-config the # of partitions to get more parallelism

check number of partitions

```
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

check shuffle partitions

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
```

check other configs like executor ram, cores, and instances

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

spark is a tough beast to tackle ... best visit their official documentation to learn more! https://spark.apache.org/

Comment: Thank you. I will check and update if I find any improvement.

Comment: One more question that I had was, if the same logic is implemented in Java or Scala, would it improve the performance ?

Comment: i think it depends on the logic ... usually scala is always faster because it is spark's native language ... btw unless i misinterpreted your question wrong approx 10 secs is not slow when persisting or collecting back to driver on a small data set like 10K ... are you performing any aggregations/joins prior? also, collect() is not recommended to use on larger data sets because it returns the entire object back to the driver and can crash it

Comment: Yes, I am performing aggregation and join before collecting the JSON data. Ok, so for the large data sets if I want to have a JSON text of the 10 K rows, do you suggest any alternate approach other than collecting it? Please advise.

Comment: why are you collecting the data?  you can write df out to json files ... ex => df.write.json('path')

Comment: Writing to JSON files is taking 24 secs which is more than collecting data takes [16 secs]. I need to send the JSON data back to webservice, so collecting in memory and sending it back is more convenient rather than write to files and sending the file path. Moreover, the JSON data is written separately into different files [200 part files]. Maybe because, the number of partitions are 200 after the groupby operation.

Comment: oh ok ... well not sure how to deploy the API call but you could try caching the dataframe to load into memory prior to colelcting ... so df.cache() as well as reduce the # of partitions via the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions config prior to aggregation ... this should help speed it up ... also want to make sure your partitions aren't too small or skewed ... a few MB is best like 25-100 MB per partition